# How to call a goroutine inside of a select case that runs in the scope of the select's parent

Tags: select, go, channel, goroutine

I am building a data tool that collects data in a stream and operates on it. I have a main routine, a "process manager", which is responsible for creating new routines of an accumulation function. The manager is informed to create the routines based on a channel receive select case which it is running in an infinite for loop (I already have my cancel routine for itself and all of the routines it creates). The problem is that the manager needs to be able to run the goroutine accumulators in its main scope so that they can operate outside of the select and for loop's scope (I want them to keep running while the manager accepts new cases).

```
cancel := make(chan struct{})
chanchannel := make(chan chan datatype)

func operationManager (chanchannel chan chan datatype, cancel chan struct{}) {
for {
 select {
  case newchan := <- chanchannel:
    go runAccum(newchan, cancel)
  case <- cancel:
    return
 }
}
}

func runAccum(inchan chan datatype, cancel chan struct{}) {
for {
 select {
  case data := <- inchan;
    //do something
  case <- cancel:
    return
 }
}
}
```

This is a very, very dumbed-down example of my use-case, but I hope it illustrates my problem's component pieces. Let me know if this is possible, feasible, reasonable, inadvisable; And no, this is not how I implemented my teardown haha

Comment: what's the problem exactly? your example will spawn new goroutines when it needs to and they will run independently of the manager loop.

Comment: I jumped the gun on this question; really I hadn't realized that the go routines would only close in the case that the whole program completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "scope" to goroutines. All goroutines are equal.
There is "scope" for closures but your goroutines do not span closures.
So all your goroutines spanned by `go runAccum(newchan, cancel)` will be like any other goroutine you span, no matter from where.

I assume you did not test your solution?

Comment: while goroutines on the same function execute the same code, the data can be different. The data that is reachable by a goroutine could be said to be in its scope. So unless it is clear what the questioner actually wants your answer does not help IMO.

Comment: I believe my explanation "scope" and that there is no such thing for goroutines per se is correct (modulo some details about special goroutines used by the runtime). My answer tries to explain that there is no concept of "scope" local to a function or a select or a block for goroutines. This understanding might help the OP understand why the presented code already does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I think that "scope" is commonly used to describe what data can be reached by something (function, object, instance, ...). A goroutine has a scope (that of the called function). This function has a scope. So I think that there are scopes for goroutines. While you might be right that the code of the OP is already doing what he wants but we do not know...

Comment: Maybe this is nitpicking: The function executed in the goroutine has some scope - as you said that of the called function or a closure, but the goroutine itself is not scoped.

Comment: Yes I didn't test it and have been approaching go routines incorrectly then, thank you for your answer